# No Revival Badge?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

A couple days ago I edited my answer to [Shaving on Chol Hamoed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10707/759), a question originally asked on 16 Oct 2011 and originally answered by me 38 days later on 23 Nov 2011. At the time of my edit both existing answers each had one upvote and no downvotes. (There are no deleted answers, nor were there any edits to the original answer which would have allowed for a vote's removal.) Around 23:29 SE time, someone came and upvoted both answers. Based on this picture from my user reputation page: [image: my rep page]
and this picture from the other answerer's user reputation page: [image: his rep page]
it seems the voter voted for my answer 29 seconds before he voted for the other answer, making mine an answer poster 30 days after the question was asked and the first to receive 2 votes. I waited a few days and have not received a [Revival Badge](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/59/revival). Is this a bug? Does the badge not distinguish (bydesign or by accident) between votes so close in time? Shouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this can be interpreted as a bug, it will have to remain [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), due to technical constraints on our database.

The most correct query would be too taxing to run very often, so we fudge it a bit, relying on previously saved data that results in about a 15 minute window where if two competing votes come in, the badge might not get awarded (as happened to you).

I've manually awarded you the badge, since you did meet the criteria we put forth, but I'm not going to go looking for more - you'll have to find them yourself :)

Comment: Thanks!​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Found one :) http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3043/759